# python export() got multiple values for argument 'format'

Tags: python, audio, nlp, wav, pydub

i have a wav file and i want to split according to the data i have in a list called speech and to export the the splitted wav files in folders according to the label variable

```
  label=speech[0]
  start= speech[1]
  end = speech[2] 
  newAudio = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_file_path)
  newAudio = newAudio[start:end]
  if label==1:
    newAudio.export('/content/',x,'.wav', format="wav")
  else:
    newAudio.export('/content/',x,'.wav', format="wav")
```

but i keep getting the error export() **got multiple values for argument 'format'**

Comment: Try `newAudio.export('/content/{}.wav'.format(x), format="wav")`

Comment: x is a just an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition of `export` is as follows:

```
export(self, out_f=None, format='mp3', codec=None, bitrate=None, parameters=None, tags=None, id3v2_version='4', cover=None)
```

I think what you're trying to do with your first parameter is a string concatenation, e.g. change it to a f-string:

```
newAudio.export(f'/content/{x}.wav', format='wav')
```

Comment: it works but the  audio files generated are empty 
ps:my original file is not empty